# PHP PDO multiple statements executed with same variable

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm not entirely sure what PHPs PDO queries are doing under the hood.  Still new to using them.  Here's my question.  Is this safe?

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("{some sql statement}");
$sth->execute();

$sth = $dbh->prepare("{an entirely different sql statement}");
$sth->execute();
```

Could reusing the `$sth` variable like this cause any issues?  I wasn't sure if i could get into some timing issues or if this was indeed a safe practice.

Comment: oh and it needs to be `$sth->execute();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `$sth` is a pointer to a statement handler in memory. By assigning a second prepared query to it, the first statement handler has no more pointers to it, and will bee cleaned up by the *garbage collector*.

Answer (score 1):

It's not running parallel, there should be no problem here.

Answer (score 1):

No problem, you're redeclaring it so the previous one gets destroyed. Only issue I see is if you have uncommitted data you'll lose it.